# Ionic framework 'loading please wait...' control and Amplify Hub events integration

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, ionic-framework, aws-amplify

Using the ionic ion-loading dialog, I wanted to utilize the AWS amplify hub event system to control when to show a "Please wait.... Loading" during network calls.  This would in theory make it easy to control these dialogs from any component by creating events that the app component would listen and respond.

While this works when the event originates from the app component, when I create a "loading" event from inside a child component, I can confirm that the event is heard/responded to by the app component through debugging, however, the dialog does not actually appear.

Is this a valid approach, and if so, does anyone know what is wrong?

Control: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/loading

```
constructor(
    public loadingController: LoadingController
) {}

loading: any

async ngOnInit() {   
    this.loading = await this.loadingController.create({
      cssClass: 'my-custom-class',
      message: 'Please wait...',
      mode: "ios",
    });
}

// Listen for loading events from the Amplify Hub and then present or dismiss the "please wait" indicator
Hub.listen("App", async ({ payload: { event, data } }) => {
  switch (event){
    case "loading":
      await this.loading.present();
      break;
    case "finishedLoading":
      await this.loading.dismiss();
      break
  }
});

// Raising events
Hub.dispatch('App', { event: 'loading', data: '', message: ""});
Hub.dispatch('App', { event: 'finishedLoading', data: '', message: ""});
```

Comment: I prefer to use angular interceptors for this. Built into Angular. Read more here:
https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8

Comment: Thanks and I appreciate that info.  I do use interceptors for other reasons and will look into using them for this purpose.  However what I'm trying to determine primarily is why I am unable to display the dialog box when the event is fired off by a child component.  I am relatively new at ionic/angular.  Thank you!